# From current date working backwards to a certain date, display month and year

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So the problem I'm trying to solve is something like this.. given a date (early join date) work backwards from now. so in this example, I have a date of 2021, July 25th.

I need to put this in an array moving backwards from now in a certain format. So like..

August 2022
July 2022
June 2022
May 2022
April 2022
March 2022
February 2022
January 2022
December 2021
...
July 2021

I got this to the point where this works for two years, not sure how to refactor this in a way where I can do this for x # of years.. also is this easier with moment?

```
function getMonthDifference(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) {
  return (
    endDate.getMonth() -
    startDate.getMonth() +
    12 * (endDate.getFullYear() - startDate.getFullYear())
  )
}

const earliestDateJoined = "2020-07-25"
const now = new Date()
const earliestDate = new Date(earliestDateJoined)


for (let i = 0; i < getMonthDifference(earliestDate, now) + 1; i++) {
  let month = new Date().getMonth() + 1 - i
  let year = new Date().getFullYear()
  // console.log("before", year, month)
  if (month < 1) {
    month = month + 12
    year = year - 1
    if (month < 1) {
      month = month + 12
      year = year - 1
    }
  }
  const nameMonth = {
    1: "Jan",
    2: "Feb",
    3: "Mar",
    4: "Apr",
    5: "May",
    6: "Jun",
    7: "Jul",
    8: "Aug",
    9: "Sep",
    10: "Oct",
    11: "Nov",
    12: "Dec"
  }
  console.log(year + " Year " + nameMonth[month] + " Month ")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getMonths(startDate, endDate) {
    let arr = [];
    let startMoment = moment(startDate).startOf('month');
    let endMoment = moment(endDate).startOf('month');
    do {
        arr.push(startMoment.format('MMMM YYYY'));
    } while(startMoment.add(1, 'month').diff(endMoment) <= 0);
    return arr;
}
let arr = getMonths(new Date('2020-07-25'), new Date());
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the while loop.

I imagine you started with one `if (month < 1)`, but you noticed it broke when going back more than a year. So you added another, but you know you can't keep doing that. If you used a while loop instead, you could repeat the same arithmetic until `month >= 1`.

That being said, it would probably be easier to use something like this:

```
const yearsAgo = Math.floor(monthsAgo/12);
const monthsAgoRemainder = monthsAgo % 12;
```

That way you can calculate the number of years from the total number of months in one go.

Interestingly, the `for` loop you use earlier would probably also be better as a while loop. You use `getMonthDifference` to figure out ahead of time how many iterations you'll need, but with a while loop you can just wait until you hit the target date. The downside is you must ensure the while loop always exits.

As for using moment or a similar library: yes, that'll probably simplify the whole thing a lot. I mention the while loops because it's an important tool to have in your back pocket.